# The fastest possible way to catch the screen? Any Language

Tags: language-agnostic, screen, screenshot, capture

I need to take print-screens of a Windows application very very fast to make a video out of it... I have been using C# all the way, but I'm open to any language in which this process may be faster.

I have used many techniques:

- .net functions: Bitmap.CopyFromScreen()
- GDI
- Direct3d/DirectX

The fastest I've got was using GDI and still I get less than 10 fotograms per second. I would need a bit more than that, at least 20 or 30...

It seems very strange to me that such a simple operation is so demanding. And it looks as if using a faster cpu doesn't change the situation.

What can I do? Is it possible to directly capture the drawing of an application using gdi or something? Or maybe even lower-level functions to catch the info being thrown to the graphics card?

Any light on this issue would be pretty much appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is "fotogram" an actual word?

Comment: There are many many apps that do this beautifully. Are you sure you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Let's see... is this a "useful apps" site, or a programming question site? It's one of them, but I keep forgetting which.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of programs use a driver and allows your application to hook into the lower level display routines. I'm not exactly sure how this is done, but it is possible.
Here is a starting point on writing Windows driver. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809956.aspx

Here is something I just found via Google:
http://www.hmelyoff.com/index.php?section=17

Comment: Google link is dead. It would help to have an excerpt, for such occasions.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something like [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp). Depends on why you're making the video.

I use a rewritten version of Jeff's [User-Friendly Exception Handling](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000014.html), and he uses BitBlt from GDI to capture screenshots. Seems fast enough to me, but I haven't benchmarked it, and we just use it for one-at-a-time shots when there's an unhandled exception thrown.

```
#region Win32 API screenshot calls

// Win32 API calls necessary to support screen capture
[DllImport("gdi32", EntryPoint = "BitBlt", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int BitBlt(int hDestDC, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, int hSrcDC, int xSrc,
                                 int ySrc, int dwRop);

[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "GetDC", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int GetDC(int hwnd);

[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "ReleaseDC", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int ReleaseDC(int hwnd, int hdc);

#endregion

private static ImageFormat screenshotImageFormat = ImageFormat.Png;

/// <summary>
/// Takes a screenshot of the desktop and saves to filename and format specified
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName"></param>
private static void TakeScreenshotPrivate(string fileName)
{
    Rectangle r = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(r.Right, r.Bottom))
    {
        const int SRCCOPY = 13369376;

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            // Get a device context to the windows desktop and our destination  bitmaps
            int hdcSrc = GetDC(0);
            IntPtr hdcDest = g.GetHdc();

            // Copy what is on the desktop to the bitmap
            BitBlt(hdcDest.ToInt32(), 0, 0, r.Right, r.Bottom, hdcSrc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            // Release device contexts
            g.ReleaseHdc(hdcDest);
            ReleaseDC(0, hdcSrc);

            string formatExtension = screenshotImageFormat.ToString().ToLower();
            string expectedExtension = string.Format(".{0}", formatExtension);

            if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) != expectedExtension)
            {
                fileName += expectedExtension;
            }

            switch (formatExtension)
            {
                case "jpeg":
                    BitmapToJPEG(bitmap, fileName, 80);
                    break;
                default:
                    bitmap.Save(fileName, screenshotImageFormat);
                    break;
            }

            // Save the complete path/filename of the screenshot for possible later use
            ScreenshotFullPath = fileName;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Save bitmap object to JPEG of specified quality level
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bitmap"></param>
/// <param name="fileName"></param>
/// <param name="compression"></param>
private static void BitmapToJPEG(Image bitmap, string fileName, long compression)
{
    EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, compression);
    bitmap.Save(fileName, codecInfo, encoderParameters);
}
```

Comment: Chris, the gdi solution I did is very similar to the one you posted, but since it has some differences I decided to try it out. However, it does not recognize the functions "GetDC", "BiBlt" and "ReleaseDC". Are these functions written by you? Could you provide me with them?

Comment: Those functions are the ones referenced by the DllImport attributes. I believe those should reference gdi32.dll and user32.dll automatically.